# Whats the meaning of this syntax inside subscribe?

Tags: angular

```
.subscribe(data=> {
    this.timezones = data;
}
```

.is data => the same as used in the constructor (private: data)
          what is the arrow and what does it do ?

```
export class Xx implements OnInit {

  timezones: Object;

  constructor(private api: ApiService, private data: TimezoneService) { }
  registered: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getTimeZone().subscribe(data=> {
      this.timezones = data;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You should research arrow functions in javascript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Here, `data` just a local scoped variable that consumes the response after subscription. You can name it anything. And remember, it isn't related to any outer variable like in constructor or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .is data => the same as used in the constructor (private: data)
>   No, it's a variable which stores the response of subscription.
>
> what is the arrow and what does it do?
>   Here, arrow refer for arrow function which is a new way to declare a function in ES6

This is like

```
.subscribe(
    function(data) {
        this.timezones = data;
    },
    function(error) {
    },
 )
```

With arrow function

```
.subscribe(
    (data) => {
        this.timezones = data;
    },
    (error) => {
    },
 )
```

OR

```
.subscribe(
    data => {
        this.timezones = data;
    },
    error => {
    },
 )
```

I think [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrow-functions-in-javascript/) helps you to understand arrow function.